# How to save HTML element ID and its hierarchy in Database column?

Tags: javascript, html, database, dom

I want to save an element's ID in a database column. 
I also need to save the complete DOM hierarchy of that element in the same column. Later i will use this column information to get the value of that element using JavaScript parsing and traversing.

I am uncertain about which pattern to use to save this information.

e.g:

I am thinking about following patterns:

```
elementLocation = "iframe[iframeName],iframe[iframeName2],element[elementID]"
elementLocation= "frame[frameName],frame[frameName2],element[elementID]"

elementLocation= "i[iframeName],i[iframeName2],e[elementID]"
elementLocation= "f[iframeName],f[iframeName2],e[elementID]"
```

Please suggest a better pattern that can be used to represent any kind of hierarchy.

Comment: Are the iframes on the same domain? Otherwise you will encounter problems with the access rights between frames.

Comment: @yunzen : yes in same domain. Dear that is not part of question. i want to know a standard way to represent an element hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [XML Path language](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: thanks for traversing tutorial. But i need to define a pattern to save  element's hierarchy information

Comment: this is exactly what the XPath spec defines, what else do you need? are you looking for a way to represent the element's inner DOM tree, rather then its path?

Comment: i need to save element identification in a DB column. later i will use that to fetch the value of element.

Comment: you have to decide: `i need to define a pattern to save element's hierarchy information` or `i need to save element identification`?

Comment: The answers there. The XPath can be used to determine every single element in the page via it's DOM path from root to element.